# How does the smart toothbrush detect regions

Tags: algorithm, gesture-recognition

I recently came across a product called Kolibree on kickstarted, which is a smart toothbrush. From what they say on their website, it seems that Kolibree can detect each tooth. I have some exposure to gesture recognition and flight dynamics (roll angle, pitch angle, heading angle, ...) the technologies I believe need be used in this product, but I'm confused how it can accurately detect EACH tooth ? I think we can detect the left, right, up and down region using roll and pitch angle, maybe a little more precisely by using the heading angle. but accurate to each tooth is beyond my understanding. Could someone shed light on this ?

thanks,

Ted

Comment: Could we have links please to this product? [here](http://www.kolibree.com/en/) and [here](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2134904849/kolibree-the-worlds-first-connected-electric-tooth)

Comment: Yes, sorry to forget posting the links;  http://www.kolibree.com/en/ - the link to their official website https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2134904849/kolibree-the-worlds-first-connected-electric-tooth - the link to the kickstarter website

Comment: @TedCheng what sort of sensors does it have ? something like ir can give and idea of depth which would help get the gaps between teeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the kickstarter video it has:

- Accelerometers
- Gyroscopes
- Magnetometers

These provide relative position and absolute direction of the device

So how to detect tooths? I would start with this:

1. tooth shape

   - by brushing you can collect surface data of close proximity to brush
   - but only when no significant surface movement is detected then
   - this can differentiate tooth types by curvature shape/size
   - so you have an idea in what part of jaw you are
2. vibrations

   - spinning brush creates noise pulses in accelerometer readings
   - these should be dependent on the movement and surface shape
   - when linear movement is detected (you move brush from side to side)
   - then the gaps between tooths will create measurable readings in acceleration
   - this can be used to recognize relative tooth position
3. angular constraints

   - when we brush teeth on the left/right side or up down of the mouth
   - we hold the brush differently
   - this can be also measured
   - if overall angular position is within certain borders
   - then we can assume which side of mouth are actually brushing
4. when you put all these data together

   - then we can improve the accuracy of tooth scan to better numbers
   - also if some kind of calibration is used that can improve it more
   - for example hold/click some button to start calibration
   - and move around the mouth by specific calibration movement ...

[notes]

some things that have to be taken in mind

- left/right handed people hold the brush differently
- this goes also for motoric dis-functions (disabled people)
- missing or curved tooth anomalies (can be later used as mark point)
- my guess is by adding camera info (for example from the linked device)
- for head/jaw position detection can improve detection even more

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation, which gives me a good start.

Comment: Hi Spektre I have a question regarding to the angular constraint you described. How is the initial heading angle relative to the teeth/mouth be calculated? I know we can get the heading angle relative to magnetic North Pole by using the accelerometer and magnetometer. But in this particular situation, the heading angle relative to mouth is what we really need, right? Since all the consequent brush movement depends on this angle, right?

Comment: @TedCheng from single measurement you can not because you do not know how is the person oriented and also the head can be turned in any angle. but when you star scanning the surface points then you can assume normal to the surface and be relative to it. also I suspect while moving in specific direction along angle constraint our bone/muscle structure will make specific path curvature of the brush which have to be properly analyzed on big enough bunch of people to assume possibility of usage. There are most likely other possibilities but these two hit me first...

Comment: thanks, that's basically what I can imagine. I think probably their games will force user to start with a particular position, like place the toothbrush head right on and parallel to the anterior buccal and start the game. Then the relative angles of consequent movements can be calculated. Interesting product, I'll get one when it's on market and see how it works. Thanks again!